# Do I just put the html in a page when enqueueng or do I also have to reference js file from the html page

Tags: javascript, html, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to get my javascript to work in my page, but I have always just put the html on the actual page, but now am wondering if I am supposed to put the <script src before the html as well to make the code work in order to reference the javascript. I have enqueued everything, the js and css from the functions.php
Here it is:

```
<script src='https://artandleatherspencer.local/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/js/myscript.js)

<div id="clockContainer">

<div id="hour"></div>

<div id="minute"></div>

<div id="second"></div>

</div>
```

here is the code in the functions.php:

```
function childtheme_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('mytheme_main_style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_register_script('main-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js');
    if( is_page(507) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_parent_styles');
```

and here the javascript in main.js in js folder

```
console.log('executing scripts.js');

setInterval(() => {
    d = new Date(); //object of date()
    hr = d.getHours();
    min = d.getMinutes();
    sec = d.getSeconds();
    hr_rotation = 30 * hr + min / 2; //converting current time
    min_rotation = 6 * min;
    sec_rotation = 6 * sec;
 
    hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hr_rotation}deg)`;
    minute.style.transform = `rotate(${min_rotation}deg)`;
    second.style.transform = `rotate(${sec_rotation}deg)`;
}, 1000);
```

css: in style.css file

```
#clockContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 40vw;
    /*to make the height and width responsive*/
    width: 40vw;
    background: url(clock.png) no-repeat;
    /*setting our background image*/
    background-size: 100%;
}
  
#hour,
#minute,
#second {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
  
#hour {
    width: 1.8%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 48.85%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
  
#minute {
    width: 1.6%;
    height: 30%;
    top: 19%;
    left: 48.9%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
  
#second {
    width: 1%;
    height: 40%;
    top: 9%;
    left: 49.25%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code doesn't define what `hour`, `minute`, or `second` are. You need to assign them to elements in the DOM. This is a purely JavaScript issue and best asked at stackoverflow.com, if you're not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enqueue a script with `wp_enqueue_script()` it adds the `<script>` tag part for you. If you have HTML that the script interacts with you will need to add that HTML to the page another way. You should *not* include the script tag in any HTML.

There are many options for adding HTML to a page, depending on where you need it:

- Adding it in the Text tab of the classic editor.
- Adding it with the Custom HTML block in the block editor.
- [Creating your own block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/).
- [Creating a shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/).
- [Creating a widget](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/).
- Adding it to a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

Although I'd say that anything other than using a block is becoming obsolete at this point.